# apache2 force proxy for specific url on a subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I have a site that has dynamic virtual subdomains using mod_rewrite, as defined like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName    example.com
    ServerAlias    *.example.com

    DocumentRoot    /var/www/example.com/www

    RewriteEngine    on
    RewriteCond    %{HTTP_HOST}    ^[^.]+\.examle.com$
    RewriteRule    ^(.+)            %{HTTP_HOST}$1    [C]

    RewriteRule    ^([^.]+)\.example.com(.*)    /var/www/example.com/$1$2

</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that I want a specific url, say subdomain.example.com/CONTROL/ to point back to www.example.com/ using a proxy (not url redirecting).

I have tried adding:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.example.com/CONTROL(.*)    /var/www/example.com/www$2 [P]
```

But that didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From the [RewriteRule docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) section on `[P]`:

> You must make sure that the
>   substitution string is a valid URI
>   (typically starting with
>   http://hostname) which can be handled
>   by the Apache proxy module.

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}              ^subdomain.examle.com$
# [L] means stop processing after this rule
RewriteRule   ^/CONTROL/(.*)            http://www.example.com/$1 [P,L]

RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}              ^[^.]+\.examle.com$
RewriteRule   ^(.+)                      %{HTTP_HOST}$1

RewriteRule   ^([^.]+)\.example.com(.*) /var/www/example.com/$1$2
```

Make sure you have the proxy modules loaded. If you have trouble enable verbose logging with:

```
RewriteLog      /path/to/rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 9
```

Comment: The thing is, I don't just want subdomain.example.com/CONTROL, I also want all my other virtual subdomains to have the same feature, e.g. subdomain2.example.com/CONTROL.  So I did this:

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}              ^[^.]+\.example.com$
RewriteRule   ^(.+)                      %{HTTP_HOST}$1


RewriteRule   ^/CONTROL/(.*)            http://www.example.com/$1 [P,L]

RewriteRule   ^([^.]+)\.example.com(.*) /var/www/example.com/$1$2

The log says it's applying the patter /CONTROL(.*) to the url, but it never maps to the primary domain, treating CONTROL as a directory

Comment: Can you show us the rewrite log for one request? Instead of adding comments please add the information (including the above) to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) for the HTTP_HOST

the RewriteRule's are applied to the [URL path](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Syntax) only!

Comment: I disagree.  I have this already, which helps to properly map the hostname to a directory.

    RewriteCond    %{HTTP_HOST}    ^[^.]+\.examle.com$
    RewriteRule    ^(.+)            %{HTTP_HOST}$1    [C]

The problem I'm having is almost the opposite one.  Conceptually I want to undo the rewrite rules when a specific path is passed after the host name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond    %{HTTP_HOST}    ^subdomain.examle.com$
RewriteRule subdomain.example.com/CONTROL/(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [P]
```

Comment: When I try this, the mod_rewrite works, mapping subdomain.example.com/CONTROL to http://www.example.com/ via proxy, but I get 403 FORBIDDEN in the browser, which I do not get when I go directly to http://www.example.com

Comment: k, I got it.  I had to modify my mod_proxy settings to allow from localhost.  Now I no longer get the 403 FORBIDDEN and the site loads properly (with broken links of course, but that can be fixed with more rewrite rules I think)